# How can we use .xml file to truncate a table when server(JBOSS) started?

Tags: jboss

How can I truncate table when jboss server started ?
Can we use mysql-ds.xml ?
HOw can we use xml to truncate a table ?

HINT :- I saw jboss creates timer table automatically when server started using .xml file.
        But I want to truncate a table using xml file.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This has been closed.We have to modify server file in server/default/deploy/jms/hsqldb-jdbc-state-service.xml by appendig truncate coomand